# C++Builder > binary number 0b1 causes error E2141

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-xe4

I am using C++ Builder XE4.

I am trying to use a binary number such as `0b1` in my code.

Following is the code I tried:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    int num = 0b11;
}
```

The above causes a compiler error:

> Unit1.cpp(19): E2141 Declaration syntax error

Does C++Builder support binary numeration like this?

I confirmed that `0x11` works in C++Builder.

I also confirmed that `0b11` can be used in IDEOne using C++:

http://ideone.com/oy4aIZ

Comment: I'd guess the compiler simply doesn't support it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binary notation of integer literals is a [new feature in C++14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14#Binary_literals).  However, no C++Builder version has a C++14 compiler at this time.

In XE4, the [Win32 compiler](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/BCC32.EXE,_the_C%2B%2B_32-bit_Command-Line_Compiler) and [OSX compiler](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/BCCOSX.EXE,_the_C%2B%2B_Cross_Compiler_for_OS_X) do not support C++11 at all (a 32bit C++11 compiler was added in 10.0 Seattle).  The [Win64 compiler](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/BCC64.EXE,_the_C%2B%2B_64-bit_Windows_Compiler) supports C++11, though.

The current C++Builder compilers support only decimal, octal, and hex.  See Embarcadero's documentation for details: [Integer Constants](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Integer_Constants)

Comment: Thank you all. I was trying to find this kind of information using google, but without success. Now I can find it using keyword "Integer Constants". I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compile this, you will need a newer version of the C++ Builder with a C++11 compiler.

Comment: In XE4, the [Win64 compiler](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/BCC64.EXE,_the_C%2B%2B_64-bit_Windows_Compiler) is a C++11 compiler, but the [Win32 compiler](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/BCC32.EXE,_the_C%2B%2B_32-bit_Command-Line_Compiler) and [OSX compiler](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/BCCOSX.EXE,_the_C%2B%2B_Cross_Compiler_for_OS_X) are not.

Comment: However, according to [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) and [this article](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2209021), binary notation is new in C++14, not C++11.